# Achieving proper scrolling with RecyclerView, android jetpack navigation and a collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, androidx, android-jetpack-navigation

I try to implement proper scroll behaviour with the following setup in my android application.

For navigation I use the jetpack navigation in combination with a `Toolbar` layout and a bottom navigation. I also use the principle of 'one activity, many fragments'. Each item of the bottom navigation launches a corresponding `Fragment` based on my navigation graph. This requires me to use a `NavHostFragment` in my layout.

My `Toolbar` layout is part of the activity layout and gets populated based on the current fragment. Some fragments require a collapsing `Toolbar`, which also gets added when needed. But when having a collapsing toolbar I face the following problem:

In the particular case I have a collapsing `Toolbar`, the `NavHostFragment` is populated with a `RecyclerView`. In other cases it appears I can add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `RecyclerView` and get the expected result, because the `RecyclerView` is a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`. In my case the `RecyclerView` is a child of a `Fragment`, which is basically a `FrameLayout` (according to the Layout Inspector). This leads to the problem, that the layout_behaviour on the `RecyclerView` has no effect as the `RecyclerView` is not a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

I couldn't come up with a working solution for this problem. Does anybody have an idea?

**layout/activity_overview.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OverviewActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                     android:id="@+id/toolbarCoordiantor"
                                                     android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                                     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/overview_bottom_navigation"
                                                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/overview_fragmentholder"
              android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:defaultNavHost="true"
              android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
              app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
              app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/overview_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color_states"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color_states"/>
```

**layout/toolbar.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap|snapMargins"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                       android:id="@+id/expandedToolbarContentContainer"
                                                       android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                                       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                       app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                                       style="@style/AppTheme.DarkToolbar"
                                       android:id="@+id/toolbarView">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                           android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                           android:background="@drawable/round_outline"
                                                           style="@style/AppTheme.DarkToolbar.Container"
                                                           android:id="@+id/toolbarContentContainer"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

**layout/list.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dish_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap up host_fragment with NestedScrollView with needed behaviour, like this:

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:transitionGroup="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav_host" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This will prevent `scrollToPosition` method of `RecyclerView` to work. Addidionally navigating back to fragments with `RecyclerView` will reset its scroll position to the top. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59153310/3736575) for a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

[Jurij Pituljas approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381184/3736575) will prevent `scrollToPosition` method of `RecyclerView` to work. Addidionally navigating back to fragments with `RecyclerView` will reset its scroll position to the top.

A better approach is described [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-setup-bottomnavigationview-with-jetpack-navigation/). Even there is no need for the surrounding `FrameLayout`s in the referenced article. Instead of wrapping the fragment within a `NestedScrollView`, just wrap any non scrolling fragment layout views into a `NestedScrollView`.

**Activity layout with `NavHostFragment`:** No need to wrap the fragment into a scrolling view. Just set the `layout_behavior`.

```xml
...
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/navigation_host_fragment"
  android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:defaultNavHost="true"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />
...
```

**Fragment layout with root `RecyclerView`:** Nothing special to do at all as `RecyclerView` has scrolling capabilities.

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**Fragment layout with e.g. `TextView`:** Wrap within root `NestedScrollView` to add scrolling capabilities.

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="non scrolling content wrapped" />
  </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```